How to map a User to an external User if externalSecurity is Oauth 2.0 ( Cognito) with Marklogic 11.2?
I manage to create the external security Oauth2.0 with Aws Cognito.
When I go the calls to the Marklogic Application Server ( via postman) i get the user authenticated.
But it seems that is not mapped to the correct user.
I tried to map the username of the authenticated user to a ML user so that when I call the API the external user should be mapped to the one for which I put the external name.
In fact when I call the API, the external user is mapped to a Temp User with no rights.
What am I missing?
Updates:

the authentication was set to oauth.
the authorisation was set to internal.

Configuration:

OAuth Flow Type: Resource server
OAuth Vendor: Amazon Cognito
OAuthClient ID and OAUTH JWT Issuer URI were added
OAuth Token Type : JSON WEB Tokens
OAuth Username Attribute: username
OAuth Role Attribute: custom:groups
OAuth JWT Algorithm: RS256
OAuth JWT Secrets are set
OAauth JWKS URi not set

The API calls are with https.
Users have external name set to the username from Cognito
Also important to tell is that I tried also with the Authorization as oauth and tried to map roles from custom:groups to ML roles. I still have the same problem: no mapping is done... the temp user is created but with no roles.

When you created the OAuth External Security what did you select for Authorization (Internal or OAuth)? https://docs.marklogic.com/media/apidoc/11.0/guide/security/external-auth/external-auth-1.gif Does that user have anything configured for the External Name? https://docs.marklogic.com/11.0/guide/security/external-auth#id_17129

Hi. the authorization was internal and the external name was the cognito username.
I will add to the main post those and how the external security was configure

If you add and enable the following Trace Events, they will write more detailed OAuth messages to the ErrorLog, which will provide a lot more information about the OAuth Exchange.


The OAuth 2 access_token will be written to the ErrorLog.txt file. You can then cut and copy this token and paste it into a decoder such as https://jwt.io/
If you have created a Cognito group and added your user to it, you should see it in the decoded JWT

If you have created a Cognito group and added your user to it, you should see it in the decoded JWT.
{   "sub": "f6e232d4-7021-703f-30a5-3dfced5d2ae8",   "cognito:groups": [     "ml-admin-group"   ],   "iss": "https://cognito-idp.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/eu-west-2",   "version": 2,  ....   "jti": "cb9d9ffb-1ea1-4cf9-8842-0379ab3bedcc", }
Set the Roles Attribute to "cognito:groups" and add the required group to the external name of each Role (not User).

You should see the following in the ErrorLog
11:06:43 Info: [Event:id=OAuth Status] Attempting to validate the OAuth access token
11:06:43 Info: [Event:id=OAuth Status] OAuth JWT Access Token: eyJraWQiOi...... pX-ug is valid.
11:06:43 Info: [Event:id=OAuth Status] Processing OAuth JWT access token
11:06:43 Info: [Event:id=OAuth Status] OAuth Authentication with Username: [martin] Roles: [ml-admin-group]
11:06:43 Info: [Event:id=OAuth Status] OAuth temporary user created with name: [martin] with ID: [8...]
11:06:43 Info: [Event:id=OAuth Status] OAuth authenticated!
